# Is there a way to use Office365 as the authentication source SSO for a WebSite?

Tags: c#, office365, single-sign-on

We have a client that wants to utilize Office365 as the authentication source for a new web site. Is there a way to have the JWT or integrate our website to have Office365 provide the JWT or authentication?

We would like the JWT to contain the claims for each user to handle the authentication.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207239/is-it-possible-to-do-single-sign-on-with-office-365-and-third-party-web-page

Answer (score 0):

yes is possible to add on your site web a login with Office 365 identity, exactly like we can connect with Github identity for the site for example.

you could find a quick start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-overview